# Django file not found error when the file is there

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, python-imaging-library

I am working on a social media app. i have a signal that resizes the post image after upload.

signals.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def create_uuid(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  if created:
    img_dir = instance.media.url
    img_dir_list = img_dir.split("/")
    img_ext = img_dir_list[-1].split(".")[0]
    im = Image.open(img_dir)
    
    new_width = 0
    for x in range(0, 3):
        new_width += 200
        new_height = int(new_width/image.width * image.height)
        image = im.resize((new_width, new_height))
        image.save(f"{settings.MEDIA_URL}posts/{img}{new_width}x{new_height}.{img_ext}")

    instance.save()
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  media = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False, upload_to="posts"))
  caption = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="", null=True, blank=True)
  date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True, blank=True)
```

when i add a post and run the signal. it gives me `FileNotFoundError` but i can see the file in my media folder.

how can i fix this?

Comment: Maybe you should print out the file path and see if it is exactly the same as what you see in your folder.

Comment: Maybe you need to add a forward slash `/` after `settings.MEDIA_URL`? i.e. `image.save(f"{settings.MEDIA_URL}/posts/{img}{new_width}x{new_height}.{img_ext}")`